# How to fetch image in Ionic 4 with Laravel 4 api call locally

Tags: laravel, image, api, ionic4

I am fetching API call locally from Laravel 4 as

```
{"id":10,"catname":"Digital","img":"uploads\/Pz1pnU_digital.png","created_at":"2018-03-04 19:08:39","updated_at":"2018-03-04 19:08:39"},
```

These values are displayed in Ionic 4, but only the image is not displayed, the Ionic 4 code is as

```
<ion-item button *ngFor="let item of (results | async)" [routerLink]="['/', '', item.catname]">     
        <ion-label text-wrap>
          <h3>{{ item.id }}</h3> <h3>{{ item.catname }}</h3> 
        </ion-label> 
        <ion-thumbnail slot="start">
          <img [src]="item.img" *ngIf="item.img != 'N/A'" >           
        </ion-thumbnail>
 </ion-item>
```

I am getting error as ,

```
 GET http://localhost:8100/uploads/Pz1pnU_digital.png 404 (Not Found)
```

What I am missing.. I am really stuck here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your GET request for the image is not being directed to your Laravel, it is trying to pull from the Ionic app.

You need to point your src to your Laravel site.

Something like this:

```
<img [src]="'yourwebsite.com' + item.img" *ngIf="item.img != 'N/A'" >
```

Your direct solution:

```
<img [src]="'localhost:8000' + item.img" *ngIf="item.img != 'N/A'" >
```

Comment: Using above I removed the error.... GET http://localhost:8100/uploads/Pz1pnU_digital.png 404 (Not Found)   ... but still the image is not visible...

Comment: Are you adding the port yourself? 8100 should be your Ionic. Laravel should be either 8080 (I believe) if  you're using `php artisan serve` or port 80 (which can be left out when trying out an address) if you're using a web server. So the address should be `localhost/uploads/image.png`

Comment: My laravel is http://127.0.0.1:8000/ and ionic is http://localhost:8100.. so what code i  have to use?

Comment: You must use Laravel, so :8000. Right now, you are using your Ionic, so the image does not exist. I will update my answer to reflect this.